# (Some function) is not defined with SymPy Lambdify

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

So I'm writing a script that evaluates Taylor Series. However, I want it to evaluate for all types of functions. So I tried, for example, using the function `acot(x)`.

```
x = sy.Symbol('x')
f = acot(x)
...
func = taylor(f,0,3)
taylor_lambda = sy.lambdify(x, func, 'numpy')
```

The above runs without an exception (except if I use `acsch`, for example, and it does not run).

But then when it reaches this line:

```
plt.plot(x1,taylor_lambda(x1),label='taylor approximation')
```

I get:

```
NameError: name 'acot' is not defined
```

I tried to replace `numpy` with `sympy` in the lambdify call but this seems to evaluate symbolically. This is happening with some (more rare functions) but not for others. Thank you!

My imports are as follows:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
from sympy.functions import *
from sympy import pi, E,acot
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import math
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I did have similar problems before and have managed to solve them.Your line

```
plt.plot(x1,taylor_lambda(x1),label='taylor approximation')
```

looks OK.I am giving one my older code that works fine,you can just compare.

```
from sympy.abc import x
from sympy import sin, series
from sympy.utilities.lambdify import lambdify

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


func = sin(x)/x
taylor = series(func, n=6).removeO()

evalfunc = lambdify(x, func, modules=['numpy'])
evaltaylor = lambdify(x, taylor, modules=['numpy'])

t = np.linspace(-7.5, 7.5 , 100)
plt.plot(t, evalfunc(t), 'b', label='sin(x)/x')
plt.plot(t, evaltaylor(t), 'r', label='Taylor')
plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 5):

The main issue here is that the `lambdify` function uses the `modules` argument to define available modules for the supplied function. It seems `acot` is not available within the `numpy` namespace.

Lets reduce this down to something simple:

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
from sympy.functions import *

x = sy.Symbol('x')
f = acot(x)
func_lambda = sy.lambdify(x, f, modules='numpy')
print(func_lambda(1))
```

This raises a `NameError` as `acot` is not defined in the `numpy` namespace. Note the modules argument. If we extend the available modules to `sympy`, we no longer get a `NameError`:

```
func_lambda = sy.lambdify(x, f, modules=['numpy', 'sympy'])
print(func_lambda(1))
# Prints pi/4
```

If you're having trouble with odd functions, you can also add individual functions to the lambdify modules parameter as a dictionary of `func_name`: `function` pairs:

```
func_lambda = sy.lambdify(x, f, modules=['numpy', {'acot':acot}])
print(func_lambda(1))
# Prints pi/4
```

As far as plotting using matplotlib, vectorizing the equation and then plotting works for me:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
vfunc = np.vectorize(func_lambda)
x1 = np.linspace(-10, 10 , 1000)
plt.plot(x1, vfunc(x1),label='acot')
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is good, thank you. Except this will evaluate symbolically. For example, `acot(4)` will just be `acot(4)`, not the numerical evaluation that's required in order to plot values from linspace.

Comment: @rb612, yes, `acot(4)` evaluates symbolically. But `func_lambda(4)` evaluates numerically. I'll add additional details to get the plotting working.

Comment: Thank you for your response, but when I try evaluating that, I get an evaluation to `acot(4)` when printing the output of `func_lambda(4)`. But if I force to a float (using `4.0` instead), then it evaluates numerically. Is this normal?

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Not sure what I was doing previously. Regardless, conversion to a float is fairly straightforward (`float(func_lambda(4))`) if that is required. Even without an explicit conversion to float, plotting with matplotlib still  works well (i.e. tried it with `x1 = [1,2,3,4]`).

Comment: @Andrew Guy What worked well for me is: `modules=['numpy', {'acot':lambda x:np.arctan(1/x)}]`. Maybe edit it.

Comment: In recent SymPy, `acot` is automatically rewritten `atan(1/x)`. This holds for a bunch of functions which easily can be rewritten like this.