# SymPy lambdify gives wrong result, while *.subs gives the accurate one

Tags: python, math, sympy, precision

Sorry for bothering you with this. I have a serious issue and now im on clock to solve it, so here is my question.

I have an issue where I lambdify a quantity, but the result of the quantity differs from the ".subs" result, and sometimes it's way off, or it's a NaN, where in reality there is a real number (found by subs)

Here, I have a small MWE where you can see the issue! Thanks in advance for ur time

```
import sympy as sy
import numpy as np
##STACK
#some quantities needed before u see the problem
r       = sy.Symbol('r', real=True)
th      = sy.Symbol('th', real=True)
e_c     = 1e51
lf0     = 100

A       = 1.6726e-24 



#here are some  quantities I define to go the problem
lfac    = lf0+2
rd      = 4*3.14/4/sy.pi/A/lfac**2 
xi      = r/rd #rescaled r


#now to the problem: 

#QUANTITY
lfxi    = xi**(-3)*(lfac+1)/2*(sy.sqrt( 1 + 4*lfac/(lfac+1)*xi**(3) + (2*xi**(3)/(lfac+1))**2) -1)

#RESULT WITH SUBS
print(lfxi.subs({th:1.00,r:1.00}).evalf())
#RESULT WITH LAMBDIFY
lfxi_l = sy.lambdify((r,th),lfxi)
lfxi_l(0.01,1.00)
##gives 0
```

Comment: I think `lfxi_l = sy.lambdify((r,th),lfxi)` should be `lfxi_l = sy.lambdify((th,r),lfxi)`

Comment: I can't execute your code, though. I get `NameError: name 'n' is not defined.`

Comment: @Stef Really sorry, missed that while copying. Now its there. Also fixed the second comment u mentioned :) (still same results)

Comment: I just tried the code and got `NameError: name 'th' is not defined`. Please make a Working example. You've described this as a MWE where the M means "Minimal" but I'm pretty sure that the example can be simplified to be more Minimal and it should also be made to Work.

Comment: Look at `help(lfxi_l)`.  That will show you how your expression was rendered in python code.  Make sure that makes sense - you have to know Python and numpy to do that. `lambdify` does a lexical translation, without a deep understanding of `numpy`.  So there are plenty of cases where it doesn't work, or only works with scalar arguments.

Comment: @OscarBenjamin That was embarassing. I re-wrote the code, and run it on a blank notebook. It's working for me, aslo cut some extra complexity. Hopefully this is minimal enough. REALLY sorry for the mistake.

Comment: Looks like all those `Heaviside` have been converted to `select` calls.  Debugging that code is going to be a nightmare.

Comment: @hpaulj I did, there is nothing strange with it tho. I changed it so there is no 'Heaviside'

Comment: See also [Sympy name Heaviside not defined within lambdifygenerated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60171926/sympy-name-heaviside-not-defined-within-lambdifygenerated) for a workaround to match sympy's and numpy's definition for Heaviside.

Comment: naively, does this simplfy to just `lfac` so there is no need to do the calculation? or is always using `.subs()` acceptable?

Comment: @JohanC The latest version of the MWE does not make use of Heaviside and sitll the same problem occurs

Comment: @ti7  It is, and u can found that through Taylor expansion for small numbers of r (basically r<< rd). While it is correctly calculated with subs, it isnt with lambdify

Comment: The expression is ill conditioned and involves subtracting two numbers that are indistinguishable in 64 bit floating point. To get something that lambdify can work with you'd need something like a series expansion. Otherwise `lfxi.evalf(subs={r:0.01})` is the way to evaluate something like this but you should substitute all floating point values only once when calling evalf and not before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your [mpmath precision](https://mpmath.org/doc/1.2.0/basics.html#setting-the-precision) needs to be set higher!

By default mpmath uses `prec=53` and `dps=15`, but your expression requires a much higher resolution than this for it

```py
# print(lfxi)
3.0256512324559e+62*(sqrt(1.09235114769539e-125*pi**6*r**6 + 6.74235013645028e-61*pi**3*r**3 + 1) - 1)/(pi**3*r**3)
```

```py
...
from mpmath import mp
lfxi_l = sy.lambdify((r,th),lfxi, modules=["mpmath"])
mp.dps = 125
print(lfxi_l(1.00,1.00))
# 101.999... result
```

Comment: This indeed works. It doesnt work in some cases (when using Heaviside, but for the example it does). I mark u as a Correct Solution, because this seems like a general issue so others may need it too. Much ty!

Answer (score 1):

Changing a couple of the constants to "modest" values:

```
In [89]: e_c=1; A=1
```

The different methods produce essentially the same thing:

```
In [91]: lfxi.subs({th:1.00,r:1.00}).evalf()
Out[91]: 1.00000000461176

In [92]: lfxi_l = sy.lambdify((r,th),lfxi)

In [93]: lfxi_l(1.0,1.00)
Out[93]: 1.000000004611762

In [94]: lfxi_m = sy.lambdify((r,th),lfxi, modules=["mpmath"])

In [95]: lfxi_m(1.0,1.00)
Out[95]: mpf('1.0000000046117619')
```

Comment: Thing is , when the values are not modest..

Comment: as you're creating a custom function, it may make sense to wrap it in another function which defines some bounds (`if e_c not in range(..) or A not in range(..)`..) and ratio(s) (`if e_c / A > ..`..) on the inputs, explicitly raising (`raise ValueError(..)`) for unreasonable values!