# How to sympy.nsolve small values?

Tags: python, sympy

```py
from sympy import *
x = symbols("x")
y = pi*(7.92e-24*x*(1 - exp(2.47376311844078e-6/x)) + 3.91844077961019e-30*exp(2.47376311844078e-6/x))/(x**7*(1 - exp(2.47376311844078e-6/x))**2)
interval = 0, 1e-6
plot(y, (x, *interval))
```

[image: plot]

So `y` obviously has a zero close to `x=0.5e-6`.

At first, I tried `solve(y, x)` but that just kept running seemingly forever. Fair enough, I don't need a symbolic solution - I'm fine with solving it numerically.

So I tried `nsolve(y, x, 0.5e-6)` next, but that results in `0.250000500000000`. Again, fair enough, that's even mentioned in the SymPy docs:

> It is not guaranteed that nsolve() will find the root closest to the initial point

Source: https://docs.sympy.org/latest/guides/solving/solve-numerically.html#ensure-the-root-found-is-in-a-given-interval

Accordings to the docs, I should specify an interval and `solver="bisect"` so I tried with the interval that I also used for the plot above:

```
nsolve(y, x, interval, solver="bisect")
```

Which results in `ZeroDivisionError`. Probably because the interval starts at zero? Never mind, instead of using the whole plotting interval, I can be more specific:

```
nsolve(y, x, (0.4e-6, 0.6e-6), solver="bisect")
```

But even that doesn't succeed:

> `ValueError: Could not find root within given tolerance. (0.297846609020060650238 > 2.16840434497100886801e-19)`

Comment: For comparison, a query on Wolfram Alpha [https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+pi*%287.92e-24*x*%281+-+exp%282.47376311844078e-6%2Fx%29%29+%2B+3.91844077961019e-30*exp%282.47376311844078e-6%2Fx%29%29%2F%28x**7*%281+-+exp%282.47376311844078e-6%2Fx%29%29**2%29+%3D+0+for+x](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=solve+pi*%287.92e-24*x*%281+-+exp%282.47376311844078e-6%2Fx%29%29+%2B+3.91844077961019e-30*exp%282.47376311844078e-6%2Fx%29%29%2F%28x**7*%281+-+exp%282.47376311844078e-6%2Fx%29%29**2%29+%3D+0+for+x) immediately finds the desired result 4.98229e-7.

Comment: Do you have to use sympy for this?

Answer (score 2):

Lowering the precision helps this get a comparable solution quickly!

```
>>> nsolve(y, x, (0.4e-6, 0.6e-6), prec=10)
4.982288429e-7
```

Alternatively, increasing the precision will solve this quickly too

Internally, sympy uses `mpmath` which has a default precision of 15
(the backend can be set to an arbitrary collection via the `modules` arg to many functions, including `nsolve`, but of course a library must support the feature(s) you're trying to use..)

To my knowledge, `nsolve` just gives up the search faster in what's likely an iterative search after successive values are the same or within some tolerance (set by `prec`) .. I suspect here the combiation of very large and very small floats lead to a case where working with the default 15 precision simply isn't sufficient to find a match (actually experimenting down to 16 works, so your case seems especially unlucky, but not so unusual)

```py
>>> from sympy import *
>>> x = symbols("x")
>>> y = pi*(7.92e-24*x*(1 - exp(2.47376311844078e-6/x)) + 3.91844077961019e-30*exp(2.47376311844078e-6/x))/(x**7*(1 - exp(2.47376311844078e-6/x))**2)
>>> nsolve(y, x, (0.4e-6, 0.6e-6))
Traceback [ValueError omitted]
>>> from mpmath import mp
>>> mp.dps
15
>>> mp.dps = 50
>>> nsolve(y, x, (0.4e-6, 0.6e-6))
0.00000049822884287834956804705034028379641109920642909523
>>> mp.dps = 16  # just a little more
>>> nsolve(y, x, (0.4e-6, 0.6e-6))
4.982288428783496e-7
>>> mp.dps = 15  # back to the default
>>> nsolve(y, x, (0.4e-6, 0.6e-6))
Traceback [ValueError omitted]
```

see also my Answer here [SymPy lambdify gives wrong result, while *.subs gives the accurate one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71654443/sympy-lambdify-gives-wrong-result-while-subs-gives-the-accruate-one) for a similar case

(some laziness in terms.. in `mpmath`, `dps` 15 and `prec` 53 are decimal precision and bits precision respectively, but they are directly correlated/connected)

```py
>>> mp.prec
53
>>> mp.dps = 100
>>> mp.prec
336
```

Comment: Huh... thanks! Would you be able to add an explanation for this behavior to your answer? According to the docs, `prec` modifies the precision of the solution. So why does it also have an influence on if that solution is found at all in the first place?

Comment: certainly - actually I tried out my suspicion and found a better method!