# (Generic function) is not defined with SymPy Lambdify

Tags: math, lambda, sympy, differential-equations

I want to solve differential equations using Sympy.

For that I want to use the `lamdify` function but it tells me my function isn't defined, although it is perfectly defined as a sympy function.

I tried applying the advice in an older post about this but it didn't work for me.
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45273827/some-function-is-not-defined-with-sympy-lambdify]

Here is the error code:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_21432\857789962.py in <module>
      1 S2_lambda = lambdify((t, k, m, c0), S2, modules=['numpy', 'sympy'])
----> 2 S2_lambda(X, K, M, C0)

<lambdifygenerated-1> in _lambdifygenerated(t, k, m, c_0)
      1 def _lambdifygenerated(t, k, m, c_0):
----> 2     return equal(u(t), C1*exp((1/2)*t*(-c_0*sqrt(k/m) + k*sqrt(c_0**2 - 4*k*m)/(m*sqrt(k/m)))/sqrt(k*m)) + C2*exp(-1/2*t*sqrt(k/m)*(c_0 + sqrt(c_0**2 - 4*k*m))/sqrt(k*m)))

NameError: name 'u' is not defined
```

In case you need to visualise what S2 is as an equation, here is a picture:

[S2 equation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rltvA.png)

***Update:***

With the help of (Davide_sd) I've breached the previous error encountered 2 new ones.

Firstly when typing in the `ics`, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_17892\646520248.py in <module>
     28     return ED
     29 
---> 30 ics = {u(t).subs(t, 0):u0, u(t).diff(t).subs(t, 0): v0}
     31 
     32 Q2 = Q1(k, m , c0, 0, False)

TypeError: 'u' object is not callable
```

Secondly, when comenting out the ics, the code runs but runs into a math error:

```
<lambdifygenerated-1>:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
  return C1*exp((1/2)*t*(-c_0*sqrt(k/m) + k*sqrt(c_0**2 - 4*k*m)/(m*sqrt(k/m)))/sqrt(k*m)) + C2*exp(-1/2*t*sqrt(k/m)*(c_0 + sqrt(c_0**2 - 4*k*m))/sqrt(k*m))
```

And I get this result:

```
array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan], dtype=object)
```

I suspect this might be because the values inside the sqrt are negative for the inserted T,K,M and C0 values. How would I know what values are good for this function (I'm sorry I'm also a math newbie).

Here is the code extract (partial **updated** code):

```
from sympy import *
from sympy import Function, dsolve, Eq, Derivative, sin, cos, symbols
from sympy import init_printing
import numpy as np
init_printing()

x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
w0, w, xi, f, f0 = symbols('omega_o omega xi f f_0')
k, c, c0, c_0, m = symbols("k c c_0 c'_0 m")
u0, v0 = symbols("u_0 v_0")

u = Function('u')(t)
du = u.diff(t)
du2 = u.diff(t, 2)
         
def Q1(k, m, c0, f0, simplifcation):
    
    x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
    w0, w, xi = symbols('omega_o omega xi')

    if simplifcation == False:
        c_0 = 2*sqrt(k*m)
        w0 = sqrt(k/m)
        xi = c0/c_0
        ED = Eq(du2 + 2*w0*xi*du + (w0**2)*u,(f0/m)*cos(w*t))
    else:
        ED = Eq(du2 + 2*w0*xi*du + (w0**2)*u,(f0/m)*cos(w*t))
    return ED

ics = {u(t).subs(t, 0):u0, u(t).diff(t).subs(t, 0): v0}

Q2 = Q1(k, m , c0, 0, False)
display(Q2)
S2 = dsolve(Q2, u, ics=ics)
display(S2)

T = np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, num=10) # on cree des valeurs pour les 4 variables physiques.
K = np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, num=10)
M = np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, num=10)
C0 = np.linspace(0.1, 1.0, num=10)
print (X, K, M, C0)

S2_lambda = lambdify([c0, k, m, t], S2.rhs)
S2_lambda(C0, K, M, T)
```

Comment: Show the actual error; don't try to summarize or paraphase!

Comment: While I can imagine what the `X` etc print shows (that's straight forward `numpy`), I can't run the `sympy` in my head and imagine what the `S2` display shows.  And thus can't imagine the code that `S2_lambda` produces.

Comment: I have updated the post with your feedback, thanks!

Comment: Both the error and the warning tell us how the sympy was translated into python/numpy.  And yes, `np.sqrt` will raise that warning if given a negative value.  That will also explain the `nan` results.  I don't think you want the object dtype (as opposed to float), which suggests there's still a symbol in calculation (not in the sqrts, which would produce a different error).  Anyways, examine that `return` line carefully.

Comment: I tried to recreate the lambdified function from the return warning line but got too many unknown variables.  Try a simple call like `S2_lambda(1,2,3,4)`.  That should give you a number, not an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating the differential equation in the wrong way.

Specifically, you created two symbols, one representing `du/dt`, the other representing `d2u/dt2`. Instead, you should differentiate your function, like this:

```py
from sympy import *
from sympy import Function, dsolve, Eq, Derivative, sin, cos, symbols
from sympy import init_printing
init_printing()

x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
w0, w, xi, f, f0 = symbols('omega_o omega xi f f_0')
k, c, c0, c_0, m = symbols("k c c_0 c'_0 m")

u = Function('u')(t)
du = u.diff(t)
du2 = u.diff(t, 2)
         
def Q1(k, m, c0, f0, simplifcation):
    
    x, y, z, t = symbols('x y z t')
    w0, w, xi = symbols('omega_o omega xi')

    if simplifcation == False:
        c_0 = 2*sqrt(k*m)
        w0 = sqrt(k/m)
        xi = c0/c_0
        ED = Eq(du2 + 2*w0*xi*du + (w0**2)*u,(f0/m)*cos(w*t))
    else:
        ED = Eq(du2 + 2*w0*xi*du + (w0**2)*u,(f0/m)*cos(w*t))
    return ED

Q2 = Q1(k, m , c0, 0, False)
display(Q2)
S2 = dsolve(Q2, u)
display(S2)
```

Note that the solution contains two integration constants, `C1, C2`. You need initial condition to find them. If you know your initial conditions, you can tell it to `dsolve`:

```py
ics = {...} # dictionary with initial conditions. Read `help(dsolve)` to learn more.
S2 = dsolve(Q2, u, ics=ics)
```

At this point you have an analytical solution to your ODE. You can convert it to a numerical function with:

```py
f = lambdify([c0, k, m, t], S2.rhs)
```

And proceed to the numerical evaluation.

**UPDATED ANSWER**:

Let's tackle this error:

```
TypeError: 'u' object is not callable
```

This happens because you already created an applied undefined function by executing the command `u = Function('u')(t)`. So, your initial conditions should be:

```py
u0, v0 = symbols("u0, v0")
ics = {u.subs(t, 0): u0, u.diff(t).subs(t, 0): v0}
S2 = dsolve(Q2, u, ics=ics)
```

Now let's tackle this:

```
<lambdifygenerated-1>:2: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in sqrt
```

Your evaluation produced nan values: that's because you used real numbers. You guessed it correctly: these nan are caused by negative arguments to the square root function. We can use complex numbers.

Let's tackle what I believe is another error in your code. In this type of problem (mass-spring-damper oscillator), the mass, spring and damper values are kept constant: we analyze the behavior in time. So, I would do something like this:

```py
f = lambdify([c0, k, m, t, u0, v0], S2.rhs)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# insert your number here
mv = complex(10)
kv = complex(5)
c0v = complex(1.5)
u0v = complex(2)
v0v = complex(0.1)
tv = np.linspace(0, 5, 1000, dtype=complex)

# res is of type complex
res = f(c0v, kv, mv, tv, u0v, v0v)
# we are going to plot the real part of the solution
# hiding the regions in which the imaginary part is nonzero.
# hopefully, the solution at every time will be purely real
_re, _im = np.real(res), np.imag(res)
_re[~np.allclose(_im, 0)] = np.nan

plt.figure()
plt.plot(t, _re)
plt.xlabel("t")
plt.ylabel("u(t)")
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Hi! First of all, thank you so much for investing your time into my problem.

Secondly, I have deleted the symbolic declaration of my differentials.

When doing that, the code runs but I get a different error this time.
Something about an invalid value in the sqrt. I suspect this is because the inserted values for k,m,t,c0 are making out the the values inside the sqrt to be negative and that's a big no-no mathematically.

Furthermore I've encountered an error when I try to add in the initial conditions even though I've followed the template inside the help doc.

I updated the post.